# spring security @PreAuthorize not blocking requests

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration{

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/events/eventsToApprove", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_LEAD')")
    public List<Event> eventsToApprove(@RequestParam("user") String username){
        CustomUser user= (CustomUser) userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        if(user!=null){
            return eventService.getEventsToApprove(user);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Error**

```
Unexpected AOP exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor' defined in com.tracker.config.MethodSecurityConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AuthenticationManager is required
```

I am using @preauthorize on the above controller to allow only users with "ROLE_LEAD". but it's not working. Every request is coming in. Anything wrong in configiration

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess, `MethodSecurityConfig` is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`?

Comment: Something is picking up this configuration, that should be the `DispatcherServlet` else it won't work.

Comment: I am AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer

Comment: doesn't say anything. Post your class...

Comment: I mentioned this class in getRootConfigclasses()

Comment: Do you mean Initializer class

Comment: Don't add it to the servlet one.

Comment: Then where should i add that

Comment: Same class different method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90804/discussion-between-loook-and-m-deinum).

Comment: No use, i placed it even in getWebConfigClasses(). After that i got authentication manager exception. And i changed my code. stil it gives an exception

Comment: The authentication manager setup should go in the root context, the global method security enabling needs to go in the web config part. Security is added by applying AOP, AOP will only affect beans in the same application context. If your `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is in the root context it will do nothing for the controller in the context in the `DispatcherServlet`.